# ANSI C - Superfluous struct definitions?

Tags: c, struct

I saw this code in [this .c file](http://knking.com/books/c2/programs/stackADT3.c).

```
struct node {
  Item data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct stack_type {
  struct node *top;
};
```

What are the benefits of creating two structs when one would do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are looking to implement a stack. Each node contains a pointer to the next node, but each node does not contain a pointer to the top of the stack. Only the stack struct will store the pointer to the top of the stack. If every node in the stack pointed to the top, each node would have to be modified for every push or pop. The unnecessary top pointer would also be a waste of memory.

Comment: Are you wrong and Vaughn Cato is right. There is not needed to put a pointer to top, it is just for clarification. A clarification alternative could be: typedef struct node stack_type;

Answer (score 4):

It may make the code clearer to distinguish between the whole stack and a single node.

Comment: I agree with both smang and Vaughn Cato.  "struct stack_type" isn't *required*: you can just declare some variable "`node *stack_top`".  But it *is* cleaner.  You have two "kinds of things" (a "container" for nodes", and the "nodes" themselves), so it's cleaner to declare two types.  You would *absolutely* declare two classes if you were implementing this in C++.  IMHO...

Comment: Yes, a "node" and a "container for nodes" is important. This is an extension of understanding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox

Comment: Would the same concept apply to a tree data structure?  For example, struct Node { struct Node *pFirstChild; struct Node *pNextSibling; }; struct Tree { struct Node *pRoot; };

Comment: @jpen, yes it would.  Like paulsm4 said, they are two different "kinds of things"

Answer (score 2):

This way they can highlight functions, which work on a stack as a whole. Prototype will expect an instance of `struct stack_type` - you will not (supposedly) pass `struct node` from the middle of the stack.